# Feathers service does not found during fetch request

Tags: node.js, service, request, http-status-code-404, feathersjs

I make post request, by the fetch, to add new user to database.
The response that i get is 'POST http://localhost:3000/register 404 (Not Found)'. 
The problem is in the fact that, even after returning 404 to frontend, backend still continue the operation and adds user to DB.

Fetch request on frontend:

```
let res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                login: login,
                password: password,
                role: role
            })
        });
```

Backend feathers service:

```js
const registrator = {
    async create(data, params) {
        let Model = app.get('Model');
        Model.create({ login: data.login, password: data.password }, (err) =>{
            if (err) {
                return err;
            }
            else {
                Right.create({ login: data.login, rights: data.role },(err)=>{
                    if (err) {
                        Model.findOneAndRemove({ login: data.login });
                        return err;
                    }
                    else {
                        return data;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

String that defines path to this service:

```js
app.use('/register', registrator);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you should return something from main body of service.
If 'return' is inside promise, node defines it as service that do not return anything, that's why we get this error.
My service after fixing:

```
const registrator = {
    async create(data, params) {
        let Model = app.get('Model');
        return await Model.create({ login: data.login, password: data.password })
            .then(() => {
                Right.create({ login: data.login, rights: data.role })
            })
            .then(() => {
                return data;
            }).catch(err => {
                Model.findOneAndRemove({ login: data.login });
                Sentry.captureException(err);
            });
    }
}
```

This way 'data' would return only if operation was successful, so we can check result of operation on frontend part.

Comment: I had exactly the same issue. Returning a value solved it

Answer (score 1):

You are using callbacks which do not wait in an `async` function unless you turn them into a JavaScript Promise e.g. using the NodeJS built in [utils.promfisy](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Most current NodeJS libraries support returning Promises already which will make things much easier to read and follow and also ensure that errors are handled properly (in your example it won't do anything in either case).

```
const registrator = {
    async create(data, params) {
        const Model = app.get('Model');
        const login = await Model.create({ login: data.login, password: data.password });
        const right = await Right.create({ login: data.login, rights: data.role });

        // check for errors and call this if necessary
        // await Model.findOneAndRemove({ login: data.login });

        return right; // login?  what does your client expect?
    }
}
```

Comment: OP: you may want to chain promises here e.g. `await Model.create(...).then(() => { Right.create(...)}).catch(err => { return err; });  return data;`

Comment: but be mindful that returning the error object may expose sensitive data - i'd recommend using the feathers error handler which will sanitize certain fields.

Comment: I checked this code, and chain promises, still get same issue.

Comment: Also the fact that is worth to be clarifyed is that, if i will move body of service to:
app.use('/register', (req, res) => HERE);
i will not get any err. This way it works completly fine.

Comment: On frontend i want to get the status code of registration operation.